# How to change the default ios plugin in Qt using qbs?

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qbs

I have a Qt multi-platform mobile project that I want to build using qbs. I have managed to build it, but I want to link a different IOS plugin from the default one.

In the linking step, the compiler has the flags -stdlib=libc++ -L/Users/flo/Qt/5.7/ios/lib -L/Users/flo/Qt/5.7/ios/plugins/platforms -arch armv7 -force_load /Users/flo/Qt/5.7/ios/plugins/platforms/libqios_debug.a and I would like to load in my project libqminimal instead of libqios and I can't quite figure out how to do that.

So, to be more clear, I want to override all the includePaths in qbs so that I can link to the project only the libraries and plugin that I want. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: You want to override library paths, not include paths.

Comment: Exactly! But i haven't manage to do that. Any ideas of how I could do that?

Comment: See qmake docs. `LIBS += -Lpath -llibraryname`